# Extract Data from a File Unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have file that has space separated columns from that i want to extract specific data .below is the format of the file :

```
12:00:01 AM     CPU      %usr     %nice      %sys   %iowait    %steal      %irq     %soft    %guest     %idle
12:01:01 AM     all     78.13      0.00      0.98      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.56      0.00     20.33
12:02:01 AM     all     93.42      0.00      0.53      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.10      0.00      5.95
12:03:01 AM       1     88.62      0.00      1.71      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.71      0.00      8.96
12:01:01 AM       2     92.56      0.00      0.70      0.00      0.00      0.00      1.17      0.00      5.58
12:01:01 AM       3     86.90      0.00      1.57      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.55      0.00     10.99
01:01:01 AM     all     78.13      0.00      0.98      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.56      0.00     20.33
01:02:01 AM     all     93.42      0.00      0.53      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.10      0.00      5.95
01:03:01 AM     all     88.62      0.00      1.71      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.71      0.00      8.96
01:01:01 AM       2     92.56      0.00      0.70      0.00      0.00      0.00      1.17      0.00      5.58
01:01:01 AM       3     86.90      0.00      1.57      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.55      0.00     10.99
12:01:01 PM     all     78.13      0.00      0.98      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.56      0.00     20.33
12:02:01 PM       0     93.42      0.00      0.53      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.10      0.00      5.95
12:03:01 PM       1     88.62      0.00      1.71      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.71      0.00      8.96
12:01:01 PM       2     92.56      0.00      0.70      0.00      0.00      0.00      1.17      0.00      5.58
12:01:01 PM       3     86.90      0.00      1.57      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.55      0.00     10.99
```

Now from this file i want those rows that have time like `12:01:01 AM/PM` i means for every hourly basis and have `all` in the CPU `column`
So after extraction i want below data but i am not able to get that.

```
12:01:01 AM     all     78.13      0.00      0.98      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.56      0.00     20.33
01:01:01 AM     all     78.13      0.00      0.98      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.56      0.00     20.33
12:01:01 PM     all     78.13      0.00      0.98      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.56      0.00     20.33
```

Please suggest me how we can get that data in UNIX

Comment: `grep "01:01 .*all" yourFile.txt` maybe?

Comment: yes i have tried that but i want that with awk or sed i have to create a new file

Comment: `grep "01:01 .*all" yourFile.txt  > newFile` maybe?

Comment: i want that top column also how we can do that and that is not working for me

Comment: `grep -E "CPU|01:01 .*all" yourFile > newFile` maybe?

Comment: @MarkSetchell i want the columns name also this command is working for me and please describe this also how it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

if you need field specific matches awk is the right tool.

```
$ awk '$3=="all" && $1~/01:01$/' file

12:01:01 AM     all     78.13      0.00      0.98      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.56      0.00     20.33
01:01:01 AM     all     78.13      0.00      0.98      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.56      0.00     20.33
12:01:01 PM     all     78.13      0.00      0.98      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.56      0.00     20.33
```

you can extract the header as well, with this

```
$ awk 'NR==1 || $3=="all" && $1~/01:01$/' file
```

Comment: Is the header first row?  If not you can skip empty lines and print the first nonempty line as the header with this `NF&&!f++`, replace `NR==1` with that and should work.

Comment: what is not working? header? perhaps add parenthesis `NR==1 || ($3=="all" && $1~/01:01$/)`

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `-E` option to `grep` it allows you to look for *"Extended Regular Expressions"*. One such expression is

```
"CPU|01:01"
```

which will allow you to find all lines containing the word "CPU" (such as your column heading line) and also any lines with "01:01" in them. It is called an *"alternation"* and uses the pipe symbol (`|`) to separate alternate sub-parts.

So, an answer would be"

```
grep -E "CPU|01:01 .*all" yourFile > newFile
```

Try running:

```
man grep
```

to get the manual (help) page.

Comment: if have to do something like this grep -E "CPU|kbmemfree|kbswpfree|01:01 AM|PM.*all" will it work for me ??

Comment: No that will find, amongst other things, all lines that contain "PM" followed by "all" which, I guess, is not what you want. Please click `edit` under your question and describe accurately, in plain English (not code) what you want.

Comment: Mark actually in my log file i have multiple data and every data has same format but they have different column name  .So what i want i want to extract the data of all those based on hourly basis